# How to add an attribute to an element after using after() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$( ".page-header")
    .after("<p>Please enter an email address</p>")
    .attr('class', 'alert alert-danger')
    .show()
```

I want my `<p>` tag to have that attribute, but it's added to `$(".page-header")` instead. How do I add it to the `<p>`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

It achieves the same end result, but the order is swapped. This allows chained methods (like your `attr()`) to act upon the newly inserted element.

```js
$( "<p>Please enter an email address</p>")
    .insertAfter(".page-header")
    .attr('class', 'alert alert-danger')
    .show()
```

```css
.page-header { border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px }
.alert.alert-danger { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-header">Page header</div>
```